# Tableau - data contains start / end date, how to make a fixed access for every month between?

Tags: tableau-api

I have an extremely similar issue / set of data as the person from this post ..

[Tableau month-based bar chart for data with date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172251/tableau-month-based-bar-chart-for-data-with-date-range)

however the accepted solution doesn't realistically work for my case.  They suggested making 12 calculated fields, one for each month, and pivot and display.

The 2 issues I run into with this, is my data spans across 6 years
1. So 6 years x 12 months would be 72+ calculated fields
2. Also, for each additional new month, I'd have to manually create a new calcualted field

My data looks like this:

```
name   | start      | end        
john   | 2015-01-15 | 2018-03-30 
tim    | 2016-02-01 | 2017-05-15 
brian  | 2017-02-15 | 2018-04-01
```

Is there a way in tableau, to have one of the axis show every single month from the min (start date) and max (end date), so that I can tally a total for each month?

UPDATE ** As far as a metric, it would just be a "Number of Records" count.
Basically what I'm looking based on each persons start and end date, create a tally for EVERY month, showing how many employees we had for that specific month, so the output would look like (axis could be either way):

```
          Number of Employees
Jan 2015         3
Feb 2015         5
Mar 2015         6
  .              4
  .              5
  .              8
  .              7
Sep 2016         10
Oct 2016         13 
  .              12
  .              15 
  .              15
  .              15
Apr 2017         18
 etc...
```

Help or guidance would be greatly appreciated on this!

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a mockup of what you want the output to look like? And your sample data doesn't include a metric, so what are you totaling?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I just updated the question above with what I was looking to do, let me know if that makes sense, thanks again!

Comment: Two years ago I attended a class on time series analysis of temporal data that addressed this specifically. I don't have my notes handy but I'll see what I can dig up. Try a web search on temporal data tableau.

Comment: Thank you I will look up temporal data tableau!  I appreciate any notes or advice you can provide whenever you have the time, thanks again!

Comment: With a little help on what to search for, I came across a youtube video that gives me basically exaclty what I'm looking to do!!  I will post it in the answers!

Answer (score 1):

With a little help fron @Sam M on what to search for, I came across a youtube video that basically gave me exactly what I was looking to do (the video does it by week, I just tweeked the formulas to month)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZ9p-hV6-qM

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

**Another approach could be** to pivot data and then use running sum to calculate the number of employees in each month.

Let's start with your sample data

```
Name    Start Date  End Date
John    2015-01-15  2018-03-30 
Tim     2016-02-01  2017-05-15 
Brian   2017-02-15  2018-04-01
```

Steps to follow in Tableau:

- [Pivot](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/pivot.htm)
  input data to have it in below format

---

```
Name  Pivot Field Names  Pivot Field Values
John  Start Date         2015-01-15
Tim   Start Date         2016-02-01 
Brian Start Date         2017-02-15
John  End Date           2018-03-30
Tim   End Date           2017-05-15
Brian End Date           2018-04-01
```

---

- Create a calculated field `Employees Count` as

---

```
ZN(IF([Pivot Field Names]='Start Date') THEN [Number of Records] END) -
  ZN(IF([Pivot Field Names]='End Date') THEN [Number of Records] END)
```

---

- Drag `Pivot Field Values` in "Columns" section. Right click it to select
  `Month MMM YYYY` format which converts it to continuous.
- Drag`Employees Count` in Rows section. Right click it to select "Quick Table
  Calculation" as "Running Total" to have the computation using
  Table(across) and Voila!